# Trigger Jquery when user scrolls through it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger a JQuery event when the user scrolls across a div for the firs time.

I have tried using waypoint. It is not working. Here is the code, it gives no error.

```
var waypoints = $('#main').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    alert("Main div");
  }
})
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <!-- main content -->
  <div id="push"></div>
  <section class="grey darken-4 valign-wrapper">
    <div class="container valign">
      <div class="col s12">
        <h2 class="center-align white-text">Hey!</h2>
        <div class="divider"></div>
          <p class="center-align white-text flow-text developer"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>




  <div id="main">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:8px">
      <h2 class="center black-text darken-4">Profile</h2>
      <h4 class="center teal-text darken-4">
          I love to Code <a class="pulse btn-floating"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>
        </h4>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="row" style="padding-top:5%">
        <div class="col s4">
          <h4 class=" teal-text darken-4">About me</h4>
          <p class="flow-text me" style="font-size:20px">

          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
          <img src="Images/Aarth.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
          <h4 class="teal-text darken-4" style="padding-left:11%">Details</h4>
          <p style="padding-left:11%; font-size:20px;" class="flow-text"><strong>Name:</strong>
            <span class="name "></span>
          </p>
          <p style="padding-left:11%; font-size:20px;" class="flow-text"><strong>Age:</strong>
            <span class="age"></span>
          </p>
          <p style="padding-left:11%; font-size:20px;" class="flow-text"><strong>Location:</strong>
            <span class="location"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here are the approaches I have used till now, but nothing worked

```
function Utils() {

}

Utils.prototype = {
    constructor: Utils,
    isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
        var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
        var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

        if (fullyInView === true) {
            return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
        } else {
            return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
        }
    }
};

var Utils = new Utils();
```

Help would be great!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4ek9uxbe/ works fine as long as you use the jQuery version of the waypoints file. Bear in mind there needs to be enough scroll room for the top of the "main" div to hit the top of the page.

Comment: I am using 3.2.1 jquery version.

Comment: enough for you to be able to scroll till the top of the div is at the top of the page. Depends what else is on your page. You can also set an offset if you want it triggered lower down. Read the docs http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: I have tried offsets. I am sure the problem you stated is correct. I have updated the html can you please help me out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use waypoints, bear in mind there needs to be enough scroll room for the top of the "main" div to hit the top of the viewport. This will vary depending on the size of the browser window the user has open. You can set a % offset from the top of the viewport to make it trigger when the element is a certain distance from the top.

If your "main" div is the last element, you can also use the special "bottom-in-view" offset to make it work once the scroll hits the bottom of the page, even if the top of "main" can't reach the top of the viewport:

```
var waypoints = $('#main').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    alert("Main div");
  },
  offset: "bottom-in-view"
});
```

All of this information is available in the documentation. See http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/ for more details

Comment: I tried the above code earlier, still not firing. I think something else is wrong. I tried giving the minimum height thing. But still no luck,

Comment: difficult to understand what you're doing wrong. Here it is working with that code: https://jsfiddle.net/4ek9uxbe/2/ . Are you definitely including the jQuery version of the waypoints library? There are different versions of it for different integrations.

Comment: In the documentation it is mentioned 1.8.0+ versions are supported and I am using 3.2.1. Here is the page https://aarth-tandel.github.io/

Comment: at https://aarth-tandel.github.io/ there's no waypoint code at all either in the main page or the loaded JS files. Neither the library or the code I've pasted above are present. So I'm not sure what showing me that is meant to demonstrate? You don't appear to have implemented it at all, in which case it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

Comment: I just showed to give  a look at the page. I have not yet committed the changes.

Comment: I have committed the changes.

Comment: like I already said, you have to use the jQuery version of the file. `jquery.waypoints.js` in the "lib" folder of the zip file when you download it. (or `jquery.waypoints.min.js` for us in production)

Comment: I have used the same.

Comment: move `var waypoints = $('#main').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
    alert("Main div");
  },
  offset: "bottom-in-view"
});` inside your document.ready function (i.e. inside `$(function(){...});`). Otherwise it runs before "main" actually exists, and therefore attaches itself to nothing.

Comment: That Worked! How did i miss that! Thanks a lot!